# Identifying interaction terms in nonlinear data whose underlying function may be unknown

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, interaction, computational-statistics, order-statistics

This is the data that I am using to frame and ask this question (code written in R):

```
X1 <- seq(0.2,100,0.2)
Y1 <- 100 * (2*X1/(100-X1+2*X1)) - X1
X2 <- seq(0.1,99.9,0.2)
Y2 <- 100 * (1.8*X1/(100-X1+1.8*X1)) - X1
set.seed(123)
X <- c(X1, X2) + rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
Y <- c(Y1, Y2) + rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
A <- c(rep(0, 500), rep (1,500))
B <- sample(x = c(1,0), size = 1000, replace = T)
```

I havea dataset consisting of variables X and Y that are related as follows:

```
plot(X,Y)
```

[image]

I do not know the exact underlying function that connects Y to X, and I am not interested in an exact mathematical formulation of this relationship. I am happy to use a smooth spline to describe their relationship as follows:

```
Spline <- smooth.spline(x = X[order(X)], y = Y[order(X)])
lines(Spline, col = "red", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

In addition to X and Y, my dataset has two additional variables, A and B. These are categorical variables indicating whether or not a specific datapoint belongs to the group "A" or to the group "B" (these two are not mutually exclusive).

Variable A interacts with X in such a way that the curve describing the relationship between X and Y is lower if A == 1:

```
plot.colour <- rep("black", 1000)
plot.colour[which(A == 1)] <- "orange"
plot(X,Y, col = plot.colour)

Spline <- smooth.spline(x = X[1:500], y = Y[1:500])
lines(Spline, col = "red", lwd = 3)

Spline <- smooth.spline(x = X[501:1000], y = Y[501:1000])
lines(Spline, col = "brown", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

On the other hand, variable B does not interact with X and so the groups for B == 1 and B == 0 show the same relationship between X and Y:

```
plot.colour <- rep("black", 1000)
plot.colour[which(B == 1)] <- "orange"
plot(X,Y, col = plot.colour)
```

[image]

My question is: is there an "automatic" method of detecting this interaction between X and A when I don't know the mathematical relationship between Y and X? In this specific example, I can detect the interaction by eye, but I am working with hundreds of datasets, each of which involves a different relationship between X and Y and each involving tens - hundreds of different potential interacting variables. So in my real project it is not feasible for me to approach this problem "manually".

Any pointers to the methods or statistical techniques that could help me solve this problem would be greatly appreciated even if you don't want to spend time writing a full answer! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the various measures for non-linear correlations? Beginning with Spearman and dCor for example?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Anony-Mousse. How would I use (non-linear) correlations to address this problem? The correlations would improve when subsetting by A but not when subsetting by B?